# Is asking about the reasons behind game mechanics off-topic?

Tags: support, allowed-questions

### [Resulting question on Game Development.](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/109241/why-is-this-game-mechanic-so-commonly-used)

I've recently been pondering a question of the reason behind a certain game mechanic used in many games.

I was going to ask it on Arqade as the [Ask > On-Topic section](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) in the FAQ states:

> Game mechanics and terminology

but it also mentions this in the '*prohibited questions*' section:

> Speculative questions about developer intent, with respect to both mechanics and narrative

The question I want to ask is generally '*why is this game mechanic popular?*'.

Can I ask these type of questions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question would be off-topic for falling into the realm of Game Development instead of Gaming. That is, your question is best answered by people who make games and not those who play games. You might be able to ask your question on our sister site, [Game Development](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/), but you'd want to take a look through their FAQ first.

Comment: Good call. [S.L Barth](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4044122#4044122) did hint at such a question being off-topic, but I wanted to double-check. Thanks!

Comment: As it turns out, you should not ask tgis on game dev SE. Closed for being opinion based

Comment: @Timelord64 I thought that might happen, which is why I suggested checking out the FAQ first.

Answer (score -2):

If the question is, "in general, why do game designers tend towards this type of mechanic rather than that," that's game design.

However, if the question is, "in this particular games, what are the developers trying to encourage me to do, as a player, with this mechanic," I think that's a reasonable question for this forum, since the forum does seem to be for players to ask questions about how they should play games.